# Is "high cohesion" a synonym for the "Single Responsibility Principle?"

Tags: oop, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle, cohesion

Is ***high cohesion*** a synonym for the ***Single Responsibility Principle?*** If not, how are they different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The are not the same thing.

You can have a highly cohesive class that does not have just a single responsibility.

Comment: And the opposite could be true: a class that implements a single responsibility could be coupled to a bazillion things.

Comment: @jonnyGold - High cohesion (within a class) and coupling are different things too...

Comment: Indeed. However, they (coupling and cohesion) are often seen as opposites, right?

Comment: @jonnyGold - Within a class, when trying to follow good design principles.

Comment: 1 - "You can have a highly cohesive class that does not have a single responsibility." I assume that happens when class doesn't have any members? 2 - Assuming class does have members, I still don't quite understand how they are different - afterall, their definitions are almost identical

Comment: @user1483278 - My meaning was _just_ one single responsibility.

Comment: @Oded - You mean Highly Cohesive class can feature SEVERAL strongly related responsibilities, while class adhering to SRP will have just ONE responsibility?

Comment: @user1483278 - Yes. It boils down to what one calls a responsibility. For example, a data access class can be highly cohesive, but if it handles both queries and commands, someone using CQRS would see it as violating SRP.

Comment: So it also depends on the context? Meaning, if one doesn't know or care about CQRS, then for them it is perfectly reasonable to consider that class as adhering to SRP?

Comment: @user1483278 - In that specific example. Though if the class is doing anything other than data access, it could still violate SRP.

Comment: Robert Martin created the SRP, and he considers it, "[just another way to define cohesion and coupling.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54991902/1371329)"

Answer (score 23):

You asked: **If not, how are they different?**

### Single Responsibility Principle

Throw out whatever you think you guess this principle means.

Robert C. Martin officially defines this principle as:

> A class should only have one reason to change

Most people defining SRP are incorrect.  SRP is typically mis-explained as:

"The `Employee` class shouldn't `UpdateDemographics()` and `SendMessage()`, that counts as two responsibilities... put `SendMessage()` into a Message class!!"

**^^ Wrong**

**vv Right**

Robert C. Martin says

> "A responsibility is not 'something the code does'". (NDC 2012)

Robert C. Martin defines SRP as:

> "Any module should be responsible to only **one person**-[role]." (NDC 2012)

When a **Stakeholder** asks for a change to the data-sorting in the View, management shouldn't freak out and worry that the algorithms will break.  Because **The module that handles Sorting on the View is responsible only to the stakeholder**, and **The module that handles the total-calculating algorithm is responsible only to the business analyst.**  So when the Business Analyst asks to make a change to the algorithm, we shouldn't fear that the View will change.

Therefore, **A module** (singular) should only ever change for one reason: The Single Person-**Role** for whom this module serves has requested a change.

With that as your new foundation for the definition of SRP, you can now apply what you **thought** SRP was previously, and make the definition a bit more granular.  Nobody is saying to put all of your front-end code into one module and all of your back-end code into one module.

### High Cohesion

Imagine that you have a method `decimal CalculatePayFor(Employee)` and another method `void Pay(Employee)`

Do these belong together?  There could be a service that performs calculations of all sorts, and there could be a service that does nothing more than wrap the Human-Resources Payment SOAP.  Perhaps `Pay(Employee)` calls into `CalculatePayFor(Employee)`, but just because they have the word `Pay` in them doesn't mean they belong together!

**How do I create cohesion?** - You don't.  Cohesion is something you observe.  What you do is **Don't tear things apart that belong together.**

It is possible to create a class for every public method you want.  Each class now has one public method and everything is a well-defined mess.  You have classes named `PayrollClass1` and `PayrollClass2` because one does calculations one way, and the other does calculations two way.

Some languages even benefit from a complete lack of classes, and methods run free.  There is no grouping of methods, methods are just methods that you can call whenever.  They're all pretty much static.

However, **You Can Observe** that `CalculatePayFor(Employee)` and `Pay(Employee)` are actually VERY Highly *bound*.  They are like a dang married couple, and they look great together.  When methods clearly belong together, you don't want to tear them apart.  Observe their natural state and set up a wildlife preserve.  This is **Maintaining High Cohesion**.  You don't create it, you observe it.

What this really helps with is **Proper Code Duplication**.  For example, `PayrollService.CalculatePayFor(Employee)` has the same exact code as `ReportService.CalculatePayFor(Employee)`.  Is this bad?  Of course not.  If Senior Management asks to make a change in the calculation for employee pay for the sake of reporting, that's a different responsibility than if H.R. tells you to make a change for the calculation for tax purposes for the actual payment method.

"Wait, did he just mix up SRP and Cohesion?"  No, but I'm glad you recognized the mix-up.  What if the ReportService reached into the PayrollService' class and used its method?  Then when it changes for legitimate payment purposes, the reports all change... but management didn't want that!!!  So since Cohesion forces methods to stay to their own classes, and SRP forces modules to keep to themselves within an application, the ReportService is forced to Copy/Paste the method from the PayrollService class.  Now they can change independent of each other.

"But what if that isn't what you want?"  Well, there are a lot of places in code where duplication is ruled out.  But it is most common for algorithms to stick to themselves, and change independently of the dependencies.  Even if that means duplication.  It just depends what is needed.  But Separation of Concerns, Single Responsibility, Cohesion, and DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) are all separate ideas.

Side-Note: DRY Doesn't mean there is never duplication.  As I mentioned: Many times you can have duplicate code because business rules are similar amongst different concerns, and have different reasons to change.

Comment: Nobody has commented about a particular place I actually expected. So I will. It would be unlikely that the `Payroll.CalculatePay` and the `Report.CalculatePay` would need to be much different. But you'd find that while the deep core calculations should always be the same, the higher level stuff of how it organizes, groups, sorts, filters, and transforms that data would be different between the two. In that sense, the `ReportService` would call the `PayrollMicroService` to get the core details.  But each service would transform that data differently. Just to quell any concerns there :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a synonym. SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) is when you ensure yours classes will have only one responsibility. For sure this increases your classes cohesion.

But you can have high cohesion without following SRP to the letter.

[Here](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2008/6/12/is-the-srp-principle-the-same-as-low-coupling-and-high-cohesion/) is a good source on that.

Answer (score 2):

In Robert Martin's [own words](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html),

> If you think about [SRP] you’ll realize that this is just another way to define cohesion and coupling. We want to increase the cohesion between things that change for the same reasons, and we want to decrease the coupling between those things that change for different reasons.

See also: [Difference between Single Responsibility Principle and Separation of Concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54991769/1371329).