# How to not violate Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: inheritance, interface, single-responsibility-principle

I am new to programming and I am learning design things.

I was taught that SRP is super important such that every class should have one responsibility. Thus, I wanted to inherit responsibilities from other classes. But then, I realized java doesn't allow multiple inheritances, but only interfaces. I think the problem of implementing multiple interfaces is that you have to write the methods inside the one class that implements the interfaces anyways. So you have to go to the class that implements the interface to fix the method. Then isn't it considered to violated SRP?

In short, I want a class A, say dog, that construct a thing and need methods B(bark), C(eat), and D(sleep) about the A. How do I do that without violating SRP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SRP is commonly stated as "Every class should have one responsibility," but this is inaccurate. A better statement is, "A module should have one and only one reason to change." As I describe in [Single Responsibility Principle: Is It a Fundamental Mistake?](https://qualitycoding.org/single-responsibility-principle/) I can think of two possible axes of change:

1. Business change
2. Technological change

To reduce business change to "one reason to change" means there should only be one person in the business who asks you to change a particular module. For example, some of the people who might ask for a change are the head of product, or the head of design. So this means we should separate how a thing behaves from how it looks.

An example of technological change is changing how a thing is stored. "We need to change from an SQL database to flat NoSQL storage."

So what it does, how it looks, infrastructure it depends on — these are things that should be separated. Not your Dog. The Interface Segregation Principle leads to thin slices of interfaces, like Barking and Eating. This enables callers to depend on these thin slices, instead of on some huge interface like Animal that has lots of things it doesn't need.

So I'd say

```
class Dog: Barking & Eating & Sleeping
```

doesn't necessarily violate SRP, especially when each interface is thin.

That said, I've seen people slap unrelated interfaces together to create monstrosities. It's mainly a result of lazily using an existing class as a dumping ground. As long as you keep asking, "Can this be separated?" and seeing if you can extract responsibilities, you're doing better than most people.

Comment: So if all of these methods target the same properties do they belong in the same class ? However if a class has multiple properties and a method works with those properties and no other methods within the class are interested in those properties then shall I create a new class within the Animal. For example create a Swim class within fish if there are properties such as distanceSwam , oceanUsed within the Fish class which extended from Animal class which has properties such as name , weight etc?

Comment: @KevinGreetham You are describing cohesion: a high use of properties across most methods. Yes, we want classes with high cohesion. Where cohesion is low, it makes sense to perform the Extract Class refactoring to increase the cohesion.

Comment: And high cohesion means we are adhering to SRP ? How about when we have 5 methods , 5 properties. E.g User class. Method1 updates users name . Methods 2 updates users age . Method 3 updates users size etc etc. shall I keep these in the same class rather than create 5 seperate classes? However when various methods start to target one property or various properties relate to each other. E.g. users address contains street, doorNum, zip code etc then I should think about creating a new Address class as a property of the User class? Thank you

Comment: Cohesion is a higher-level principle than SRP. SRP isn't "the class does one thing" but rather "We are responsible to this person. They are asking for a change. How many different places do we need to change to accommodate their request?" For example, a person might be the UI designer, or the database manager, or the product owner standing in as a representative for one type of end-user. Each one of these is a single responsibility. When someone wears multiple hats, let's consider each hat a separate responsibility. …Feel free to hit me up if you want to work through a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Youve been a great help. The “responsible to one actor” confuses me so much though. For example , I make a game of monopoly : the player rolls a dice , the players square position changes on the board, the players buys a property etc. All of these requests are made from the player but it would be surely silly to not have a Property class, Dice class, Board class etc. thanks again

Comment: Excellent observation, Kevin. I think what we are discovering in this thread is that cohesion is not the same as SRP. They offer two different reasons to split something up. For example, you could have a fairly cohesive User class that combines responsibilities to multiple actors. And in your Monopoly example, SRP may not call for these classes but cohesion does.

Comment: Thanks Jon.There’s something nice about being complemented by experience. So a class can adhere to SRP if it responds to one actor, but can be further broken down for cohesiveness ? This is why I don’t like the “ responsible to one actor” definition because I get that some classes properties and methods  are targeted by different actors. E.g the administrator changes someone’s address and the user applies for a loan using the same name and address passed to a Loan class, but I feel like there are so many occasions where you’d seperate  classes to adhere to SRP without that definition. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 doesn’t that mean we should concentrate on cohesiveness by separating logical components that belong together over what actor is targeting what? The one reason to change definition feels equally as confusing because a class with various properties and methods of not cohesive where every method is used or at least could be used in an event then this class would always have multiple reasons to change ? If that’s the case then all of our classes would be specific to what event has taken place? 2/3

Comment: Which we can achieve through having a class grouping the methods and props together which are not necessarily cohesive and then creating a new class which has an interface where we can envoke methods from the non cohesive class That’s passed into it as a dependancy. So we have one class which has various methods and props which are not cohesive and various classes that are cohesive which a specific event invokes methods on ! Hope I’m making sense

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/11215141/246895 for more interesting discussion. It confirms that SRP and cohesion are connected, but different. Also remember that SOLID is not the lens through which we make decisions. In particular, I refer you to the Four Rules of Simple Design https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BeckDesignRules.html