# Why we use Lifecycle aware components & What is the purpose of Lifecycle Observer in Android?

Tags: java, android

We already have a Lifecycle in our Activity/Fragment then why will we use Lifecycle aware component & kindly guide me the main purpose of it.
And if we use lifecycle aware then why we use lifecycle that we knew already

Comment: Can you please provide more information on your sources? What do you mean with "we already have a Lifecycle"?

Comment: I meant to say Simple Lifecycle of Activity that we use in our MainActivity OR Fragments.https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: Did you read https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html ?

Comment: EpicPandaForce
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the Android Activity has a so called [lifecycle](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity)

But that has nothing to do with a [Lifecycle aware component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)

> Lifecycle-aware components perform actions in response to a change in
> the lifecycle status of another component, such as activities and
> fragments. These components help you produce better-organized, and
> often lighter-weight code, that is easier to maintain.
>
> A common pattern is to implement the actions of the dependent
> components in the lifecycle methods of activities and fragments.
> However, this pattern leads to a poor organization of the code and to
> the proliferation of errors. By using lifecycle-aware components, you
> can move the code of dependent components out of the lifecycle methods
> and into the components themselves.

Here´s a [tutorial](https://www.talentica.com/blogs/android-life-cycle-aware-components/) hands-on to make it more easy to understand

So why did Google Android devs come up with this technique and others in the [Android jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack)? Yes Lifecycle aware component discussed here comes from [Android jetpack from 2018.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/whats-new-with-android-jetpack.html) . They did it to make it easier for us to make robust Android apps. They are doing it to get us closer to the [SOLID](https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-s-o-l-i-d-principle-in-android-a90947f57cf0) principles. Before that, developers were coming up with their own styles using homemade MVC,MVVC or MVP. Big discussions on Singletons technique for years and of course how we best do the [separation of concern and Single responsibility principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724469/difference-between-single-responsibility-principle-and-separation-of-concerns)

Now all of that is solved for us with [Android jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack)

> In object-oriented computer programming, SOLID is a mnemonic acronym
> for five design principles intended to make software designs more
> understandable, flexible and maintainable

[WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle Observer helps you to listen app background and foreground events.

Please find below link for implementation details :

[Lifecycler Observer Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53669865/651377)